# Extract data from elasticsearch into R with elastic package, load into a data frame, error due to hits not expanding to the same length

Tags: r, elasticsearch

I extract data from elasticsearch as follows:

```
> packageVersion("elastic") [1] '0.7.8'   
# data extract  
body <- list(query=list(range=list(timestamp=list(gte="2016-10-13",  lte="2016-10-15"))))  
b3 <- Search(index="myIndex",  
        sort=c("timestamp:desc"),   
        fields=c('timestamp','A','B','C','D','E','F','G'),   
        body=body,  
        size=3)
```

the first and second elements are extracted ok (edited to save space):
$hits$hits[[1]]$fields$F,E,B,G,C,A,D,timestamp
$hits$hits[[2]]$fields$F,E,B,G,C,A,D,timestamp

the third element extracted not fully as:
$hits$hits[[3]]$fields$C,A,B,D,timestamp

==
I convert the list to the data frame as per this post:
[Convert in R output of package Elastic (nested list?) to data.frame or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29243639/convert-in-r-output-of-package-elastic-nested-list-to-data-frame-or-json)
The first and the second elements are loaded perfectly.
The third element is loaded incorrectly since not the full element is extracted, causing the following errors:

```
# (optional) verify that all hits expand to the same length
# (should be true for data intended to be in a table format)
stopifnot(
 sapply(
b3$hits$hits, 
function(x) {!(length(unlist(x)) - length(unlist(b3$hits$hits[[1]])))}
  )
)
Error: sapply(b3$hits$hits, function(x) { .... are not all TRUE

# load into the dataframe
# count number of columns, use unlist() to convert 
# nested lists to a vector, use the first hit as proxy
nColumns <- length(unlist(b3$hits$hits[[1]]))

# fetch column names ... as above
nNames <- names(unlist(b3$hits$hits[[1]]))

# unlist all hits and convert to matrix with ncol Columns, don't forget  byrow=TRUE!
df.b3 <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(b3$hits$hits), ncol=nColumns, byrow=TRUE))

Warning message:
In matrix(unlist(b3$hits$hits), ncol = nColumns, byrow = TRUE) :
data length [33] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of columns  [12]
>
```

Note: some records in variables D,E,F,G contain empty (NULL) and '-' values. I suspect this may cause the issue with the extract.

I'd love some feedback if anyone of you encountered a similar issue and found a solution.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Author here of `elastic`

We don't attempt to coerce output into data.frame's since it can be so variable that we'd likely run into errors often. But we do allow you to pass on an option to `jsonlite` to coerce to `data.frame` (via the `asdf` parameter, for *as data.frame*) as that shouldn't ever fail.

If dealing with list output, I would use one of `dplyr` or `data.table` if getting back a list.

For reproducibility:

```
library(elastic)
if (!index_exists("shakespeare")) {
  shakespeare <- system.file("examples", "shakespeare_data.json", package = "elastic")
  docs_bulk(shakespeare)
}
res <- Search(index="shakespeare", fields=c('play_name','speaker'))
out <- lapply(res$hits$hits, function(x) unlist(x$fields, FALSE))
```

`dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(out)
#> # A tibble: 10 × 2
#>    play_name       speaker
#>        <chr>         <chr>
#> 1   Henry IV              
#> 2   Henry IV KING HENRY IV
#> 3   Henry IV KING HENRY IV
#> 4   Henry IV KING HENRY IV
#> 5   Henry IV KING HENRY IV
#> 6   Henry IV KING HENRY IV
#> 7   Henry IV KING HENRY IV
#> 8   Henry IV KING HENRY IV
#> 9   Henry IV  WESTMORELAND
#> 10  Henry IV  WESTMORELAND
```

`data.table`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(out, fill = TRUE, use.names = TRUE)
#>    play_name       speaker
#> 1:  Henry IV              
#> 2:  Henry IV KING HENRY IV
#> 3:  Henry IV KING HENRY IV
#> 4:  Henry IV KING HENRY IV
#> 5:  Henry IV KING HENRY IV
#> 6:  Henry IV KING HENRY IV
#> 7:  Henry IV KING HENRY IV
#> 8:  Henry IV KING HENRY IV
#> 9:  Henry IV  WESTMORELAND
#> 10:  Henry IV  WESTMORELAND
```

Or, use `asdf` parameter, which internally directs `jsonlite::fromJSON` to parse to a data.frame if possible.

```
res <- Search(index="shakespeare", fields=c('play_name','speaker'), asdf = TRUE)
res$hits$hits$fields
#>    play_name       speaker
#> 1   Henry IV              
#> 2   Henry IV KING HENRY IV
#> 3   Henry IV KING HENRY IV
#> 4   Henry IV KING HENRY IV
#> 5   Henry IV KING HENRY IV
#> 6   Henry IV KING HENRY IV
#> 7   Henry IV KING HENRY IV
#> 8   Henry IV KING HENRY IV
#> 9   Henry IV  WESTMORELAND
#> 10  Henry IV  WESTMORELAND
```

Using:

- R `v3.3.2`
- OSX
- `elastic` `v0.7.8.9000`
- `Elasticsearch` `v2.3.4`

Comment: Thanks @sckott.  'data.table' and 'asdf' work brilliantly. 
I also noticed that the 'sort' parameter creates issues for some records in my extracted lists as the timestamp field is populated with the 'sort' value . So I don't use the 'sort' parameter, and I get a perfect output. Thanks Scott again for your help over the last few weeks.

Comment: np, not heard of the problem with `sort`. what do you mean by _populated with the sort value_, you mean the string `sort` is in each timestamp?

Comment: only in a few records I get this:      $hits$hits[[6]]$fields$timestamp
$hits$hits[[6]]$fields$timestamp[[1]]
[1] 1476489596109

$hits$hits[[6]]$sort
$hits$hits[[6]]$sort[[1]]
[1] 1476489596109    Sorry about the display. I just copied timestamp and sort from one element.